# Creating an ordered list in Django with models

Tags: django, model

I want to create a way for users to add and change the order of a list. I have the list as a model, with rank as one of the fields, and title and info as the other 2 fields. Users have the ability to add items to the list. The page will then display the list ordered by rank.

However, I have no idea how I'd add functionality for the user to re-order the list. I want the user to be able to click an item in the list and then move it up or down, and additionally be able to just type in a number they want to move the item to. I can handle the aspect of how to adjust the rank numbers, but I don't know the best way to actually access the information and update it.

Comment: Is this on a custom view or in the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is django admin, simply use https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2 package. This enables you to drag and drop your objects in your model.

If this is in frontend I believe the best way would be using ajax to send requests, and dynamically update your rankings. jQuery enables you to sort your objects https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

```
# For custom views, override your class from 'ListView' class

views.py

class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'modellist.html'
    model = ModelName
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


# For sorting, you have to use sortable jquery ui plugin

modellist.html


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
{% if object_list %}
{% for object in object_list %}
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>{{ object.rank }}</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>{{ object.title }}</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>{{ object.info }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```